# Distributed computing for .NET Scenario simulation (DAG jobs) on Hadoop/Spark

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop, apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm currently looking into a way to run a .NET DAG of jobs(scenario simulations) on a cluster using Hadoop or Spark. In both cases i ran into problems concerning the code language.

What if found is that Spark supports code written in: Scala, Python, Java and R but not in .NET. 
And Hadoop does support writing jobs in .NET, however i didn't found a DAG implementation for Hadoop on .NET.

Is there a way to implement a DAG of jobs on a cluster/cloud using .NET programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# language binding for Apache Spark is now available through SparkCLR (https://github.com/Microsoft/SparkCLR). You may be able to use that for running your .NET jobs in Spark cluster.

Answer (score 0):

**Update May 2020:**

You probably now want to take a look at the .NET Foundation's [.NET for Apache Spark project](https://dot.net/spark).